# Convergence of integral (Lebesgue and Bochner spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the following convergence:

$\int _{[0,T] \times \Omega } (v_nu_n(\phi _t + u_n \cdot \nabla)\phi) dxdt \rightarrow \int _{[0,T] \times \Omega } (vu(\phi _t + u \cdot \nabla)\phi) dxdt$

We know 
\begin{align}
(1)\ \ \ \phi &\in H^1([0,T] \times \Omega) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)) \\
(2)\ \ \ u &\in L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)) \\
(3)\ \ \ v &\in L^\infty([0,T]\times \Omega)
\end{align}

and further

\begin{align}
(4)\ \ \ &u_n \rightarrow u \ \ \ \text{in} \ \ \ L^2([0,T] \times \Omega) \\
(5)\ \ \ &u_n \rightharpoonup u \ \ \ \text{in} \ \ \ L^2(0,T; H^1 (\Omega)) \ \ \ \text{weakly}\\
(6)\ \ \ &u_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} u \ \ \ \text{in} \ \ \ L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \ \ \ \text{weakly}^* \\
(7)\ \ \ &v_n \rightarrow v \ \ \  \text{in} \ \ \ C(0,T;L^p(\Omega))\ \ \ \forall \ p < \infty \\
(8)\ \ \ &v_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} v \ \ \ \text{in} \ \ \ L^\infty([0,T]\times \Omega) \ \ \ \text{weakly}^*
\end{align}

For the first term in the integral I can see

$\int_{[0,T]\times \Omega} \! v_n u_n \phi _t - vu\phi_t \,  = \int_{[0,T]\times \Omega} \! (v_n - v) u \phi _t  \, - \int_{[0,T]\times \Omega} \! (u - u_n) v_n \phi _t  \, \rightarrow 0$,

since $u, \phi _t \in L^2([0,T]\times \Omega)$, hence $u \phi _t \in L^1([0,T]\times \Omega)$ and thus the first integral here goes to 0 by $(8)$. For the second integral one can use

$\int_{[0,T]\times \Omega} \! (u - u_n) v_n \phi _t  \, \leq \|u - u_n \|_{L^2([0,T]\times \Omega)}\|v_n \phi _t\|_{L^2([0,T]\times \Omega)} \rightarrow 0$,

by $(4)$ and since $v_n$ is bounded in $L^\infty ([0,T]\times \Omega)$

My two questions are: 
1.) Is this correct?
2.) I'm looking for a similar approach for the second term, but i couldn't find one yet. Has anybody some hint for me?

Thank you in advance for any answers.